# Trouble Writing to a new excel file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to python and got an assignment asking me to:

Design your own code in do something here part to save the title, id, share count
and comment count of each news media in separated columns of a Excel (.xls) file.

Design your own code to read the share count and comment count from the Excel
file created in step 3, and calculate the average share count and comment count of
those news media websites.

Here is my current code:

```
from urllib import request
import json
from pprint import pprint
import xlwt
'''
import xlrd
from xlutils import copy
'''
website_list = [
                'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/',
                'http://www.cnn.com/',
                'https://www.nytimes.com/',
                'http://www.foxnews.com/',
                'http://www.nbcnews.com/'
                ] # place your list of website urls, e.g., http://jmu.edu

for website in website_list:
    url_str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+website # create the url for facebook graph api

    response = request.urlopen(url_str) # read the reponse into computer

    html_str = response.read().decode("utf-8") # convert the reponse into string

    json_data = json.loads(html_str) # convert the string into json
    pprint (json_data) 

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet_test = book.add_sheet('keys')

sheet_test.write(0,0,'Title')
sheet_test.write(0,1,'ID')
sheet_test.write(0,2,'Share Count')
sheet_test.write(0,3,'Comment Count')

for i in range(0,5):
    for website in website_list[i]:
        sheet_test.write(i,0,json_data['og_object']['title'])
        sheet_test.write(i,1,json_data['id'])
        sheet_test.write(i,2,json_data['share']['share_count'])
        sheet_test.write(i,3,json_data['share']['comment_count'])

book.save('C:\\Users\\stinesr\\Downloads\\Excel\\keys.xls')
'''
reading_book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\stinesr\\Downloads\\Excel\\key.xls')
sheet_read = reading_book.sheet_by_name('keys')
num_record = sheet_read.nrows
writing_book = copy(reading_book)
sheet_write = writing_book.get_sheet(0)
print(sheet_write.name)
for i in range(num_record):
    row = sheet_read.row_values(i)
    if i == 0:
        sheet_write.write(0,4,'Share Count Average')
        sheet_write.write(0,5,'Comment Count Average')
    else: 
        sheet_write.write(i,4,row[2])
        sheet_write.write(i,5,row[3])
writing_book.save('C:\\Users\\stinesr\\Downloads\\Excel\\keys.xls')    
'''
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: now we'd like to know your issue.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stinesr\workspace\IA241\lab6.py", line 42, in <module>
    sheet_test.write(i,0,json_data['og_object']['title'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 241, in write
    StrCell(self.__idx, col, style_index, self.__parent_wb.add_str(label))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 160, in insert_cell
    raise Exception(msg)

Comment: could you [edit] your post instead of commenting? it's unreadable as is.

Answer (score 0):

The Traceback error says in the nested for-loops on `lines 40-45` you are attempting to overwrite the `row 0` from the previous lines. You need to start from row `1`, since row `0` already contains the header.

But before that, `json_data` is only keeping the last response, you'll want to create a `list` of "responses" and `append` each response to that `list`.

You need only one for-loop at line 40:

In summary:

```
website_list = [
            'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/',
            'http://www.cnn.com/',
            'https://www.nytimes.com/',
            'http://www.foxnews.com/',
            'http://www.nbcnews.com/'
            ] # place your list of website urls, e.g., http://jmu.edu

json_list = []

for website in website_list:
    url_str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + website # create the url for facebook graph api

    response = request.urlopen(url_str) # read the reponse into computer

    html_str = response.read().decode("utf-8") # convert the reponse into string

    json_data = json.loads(html_str) # convert the string into json

    json_list.append(json_data)

pprint (json_list)

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet_test = book.add_sheet('keys')

sheet_test.write(0,0,'Title')
sheet_test.write(0,1,'ID')
sheet_test.write(0,2,'Share Count')
sheet_test.write(0,3,'Comment Count')

for i in range(len(json_list)):
    sheet_test.write(i+1, 0, json_list[i]['og_object']['title'])
    sheet_test.write(i+1, 1, json_list[i]['id'])
    sheet_test.write(i+1, 2, json_list[i]['share']['share_count'])
    sheet_test.write(i+1, 3, json_list[i]['share']['comment_count'])

book.save('C:\\Users\\stinesr\\Downloads\\Excel\\keys.xls')
```

Should give you an Excel document that resembles:

[image: excel document output]